# Run bash script after application is deployed

Tags: java, weblogic12c, ear

We have a maven project that export an "ear" file at the end of building phase.
App server is Weblogic 12C. and the server is clustered by 4 nodes. after deploying the app and when the machine state is active, we have to run 3 scripts to setup app properly. they are 3 scripts for translating and something like that.
It mean we have always some tasks immediately after deploying and may be missed by operator.
I'm wonder  if there is a way to put these scripts in the ear file to be run after deploy or call them when the deploy is finish.

Comment: Q:  is a way to put these scripts in the ear file to be run after deploy?  A: Have you considered putting the "post-install" script in you Maven build.xml?  Or have you considered using something like Bamboo or Jenkins (among many other [options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps))?

Comment: @paulsm4 thanks for your reply. I don't know any thing about "post-install" and I'll learn about it. But about Bamboo and Jenkins because the deployment is happening in our customer environment we can't use DevOps facilities. we can just give them ear file and a user manual to install it.

Comment: I assumed the .ear was being deployed using a Maven "build,.xml", and I suggested adding your "post-install" script to build.xml.  Q: How *IS* the end user deploying the .ear?  Are they using Maven, or "something else"?

Comment: @paulsm4 they just get .ear from us and put it in a directory then deploy it by Deployment option in  Weblogic console's menu.

Comment: WebLogic Server supports application life cycle events that allow to run java code during specific phases of deployment/undeployment.
Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLPRG/lifecycle.htm#WLPRG357) to see if this can hit your needs.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin Thanks. what a wonderful solution! going to implement it...

Comment: Great. So, can you accept my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebLogic Server supports application life cycle events that allow to run java code during specific phases of deployment/undeployment. Take a look at the documentation to see if this can hit your needs.

Comment: you were right and I could do that via weblogic listeners on different stages (stop/start deploy and active/shutdown server) but another problem happened to me. we are in a cluster mode with 4 nodes and I wanted my scripts to be run only once and by one node which should be the last one. the question is that how can I determine   the number of nodes in a cluster programmatically and which one is the last active node? is there any facilities provided by node manager?